# Execute setpci at boot

Tags: linux, boot, grub, grub2

I'm using grub to execute two setpci commands when starting Arch on my MBA. These commands solve "startx black screen" issue for me:

```
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b=7
```

Now I want to get rid of grub and switch to rEFInd. How can I execute these commands without using grub? I've already tried /etc/rc.local + systemctl, but it doesn't seem to be working, I'm getting black screen on starting X:

```
$ cat /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b=7

$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b=7
exit 0

$ sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2015-08-10 14:37:01 MSK; 13min ago
  Process: 214 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 10 14:37:01 air systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Aug 10 14:37:01 air systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

Comment: Can you tell where in the sequence those commands execute in relation to `startx`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know. I'm not really familiar with boot processes in Linux. But I think these commands are executed way before `startx`